# Shorthand logic to prepend a variable in many languages

Tags: syntax

I'm interesting why the shorthand forms of the assignment operators only works in one way, that means appending the value of the variable.

Ex. (In Javascript):

```
x+=y    x=x+y 
x-=y    x=x-y   
x*=y    x=x*y 
x/=y    x=x/y 
x%=y    x=x%y
```

Frequently I found situations where I need to prepend the variable:

Ex.

```
x=y+x
```

Suppose x and y are strings and you are concatenating.

I would like to have a syntax that allow something like:

```
x=+y
```

As I do with i++ or ++i incrementing number.

Is there some language that support this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are languages that allow to define new operators and/or overload existing operators (see [operator overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading#Catalog)).

But operators and the use of them should be unambiguous. In your example `x=+y` could be interpreted as `x=y+x` (as you denoted) but also as `x=(+x)` (`+` as [unary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation) like negation operation in `-1`). This ambiguity can make using a language hard, especially when programmers want to make their code short and concise. That’s also why some languages don’t have [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) like pre/post increment/decrement operators (e.g. Python).

Answer (score 1):

surely x=y+x is the same as y+=x

I'm puzzled as to why you would learn a new language just to save on 1 character!

However, I would suggest JQuery's `.prepend()` method

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Comment: It gives exactly the same result. I'm not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: No is not the same in the terms of the logic of a program, suppose you have two vars, one `var html` that you build with complex functions and `var title` that you want to prepend. You want to pass `html` no `title` var. I don't want to learn a language based on this detail, i'm interesting if is some language that support this. Unfortunatly I can't downvote your answer.

Comment: Your edited answer is more useful but the idea is to simplify the syntax.

Comment: do you want to do it on the server or client side?

Comment: No matters the side. The point here is about the logic of the syntax.

Comment: well in JQuery `.prepend()` is commonly used to pretend chunks of HTML but as for a language that supports y+=x, no I don't think it does exist, I would be very surprised if it does. I would suggest you just use the regular `y = x + y;` syntax which would give exactly the same result.